# A problem about semi-direct product which is a direct product

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, semidirect-product

I have been stuck on this problem for a while now. I tried to look up similar problems with possible hints but couldn't find anything. The problems is as follows:

Let $N\rtimes_\theta H$ be the semi-direct product of a group $N$ by a group $H$ with respect to the action $\theta$, which can be defined by $\theta_h(n)=\varphi(h)n\varphi(h^{-1}),~h\in H,n\in N$, where $\varphi:H\to N$ is a group homomorphism. Then the semi-direct product $N\rtimes_\theta H$ is isomorphic to the direct product $N\times H$.

I do not see how to produce such an isomorphism. Any hints and/or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: "... where $\varphi$ is a group homomorphism"... Group homomorphism from $H$ to *where*? Are you assuming that there is a group homomorphism $\varphi\colon H\to N$ and that $\theta_h$ is given by conjugation by $\varphi(h)$?

Comment: I have edited the question above.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $N\rtimes_\varphi H\to N\times H$, $(n,h)\mapsto (n\varphi(h),h)$.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you. Could you explain how you decided that this homomorphism will work?

Comment: The element $h$ acts as the conjugation with $\varphi(h)$ on $N$. So $\varphi(h)n^{-1}$ acts trivially on $N$. But for some reason the $^{-1}$ has cancelled (I am still a bit confused about this :-) )

Comment: Ok. Thanks again.

Comment: If this answers your question, you may accept my answer officially.

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks.

Comment: Then please click the button to accept.